# suitescript 2.0 fail to evaluate

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am a novice suitescript writer and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to load a very simple suitescript 2.0 script to calculate values in a custom table.  I can upload the script file just fine but when I create the script record, I get the following error: Fail to evaluate script: `{"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"missing : after property id (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#22)","stack":[]}`

Here is the code

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/currentRecord'],
    function fieldChanged(context) {
        var fieldName=context.currentRecord.fieldID;
    //return if not one of these fields
    if (fieldName!=='custrecord_am_ehir_emp_prem_percent' &&
    fieldName!=='custrecord_am_ehir_dep_prem_percent' &&
            fieldName!=='custrecord_am_ehir_total_month_prem') 
            return false;
        else
            //get premium and percent values
        var totalPremium=currentRecord.getValue(
            {fieldID:'custrecord_am_ehir_total_month_prem'
            });
        var employeeOnlyPremium=currentRecord.getValue(
            {fieldID:'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_only_prem'
            });
        var employeePercent=currentRecord.getValue(
            {fieldID:'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_prem_percent'
            });
        var dependentPercent=currentRecord.getValue(
            {fieldID:'custrecord_am_ehir_dep_prem_percent'
            });
        var employeePremium=totalPremium*employeePercent;
        var dependentPremium=(to1talPremium-employeeOnlyPremium)*dependentPercent;
        var companyPremium=totalPremium-employeePremium-dependentPremium;
        //set field values
        currentRecord.setValue(
            {fieldID:'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_month_prem',employeePremium
            });
        currentRecord.setValue(
            {fieldID:'custrecord_am_ehir_dep_month_prem',dependentPremium
            });
        currentRecord.setValue(
            {fieldID:'custrecord_am_ehir_co_month_prem',companyPremium
            });
        return {fieldChanged:fieldChanged};
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Robert,

The property name is "fieldId" instead of "fieldID". I think that is causing the error.

Regards,
Luiz Morais

Comment: Also, should have the property "value" after the "fieldId" on object.

Comment: I changed feildID to fieldid which makes sense but I'm still getting the same error.  Any other insights you can offer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some code error in your script

1. Just like Luiz mention, change "fieldID" to "fieldId"
2. there is a typo in line 30, "to1talPremium" I believe is "totalPremium"
3. currentRecord.setValue function should follow with 2 argument {fieldId: '', value: ''}

   ```
   currentRecord.setValue(
       {
           fieldId: 'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_month_prem', employeePremium
       });
   ```

This code will not work if you using SuiteScript 2.0
try this

```
currentRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_month_prem', 
            value: employeePremium
        });
```

Let me know if you have more question.

Answer (score 0):

I think  code  should  ↓

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/currentRecord'],
function(currentRecord){
     function fieldChanged(context) {}
     return {fieldChanged:fieldChanged}
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code had a few issues but the important one that caused Module Loader Error was

1. You need to have curly-braces for multi-line scripts as follows

   else {
     //get premium and percent values
     var totalPremium = currentRecord.getValue({
       fieldID: 'custrecord_am_ehir_total_month_prem'
     });
     var employeeOnlyPremium = currentRecord.getValue({
       fieldID: 'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_only_prem'
     });
     var employeePercent = currentRecord.getValue({
       fieldID: 'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_prem_percent'
     });
     var dependentPercent = currentRecord.getValue({
       fieldID: 'custrecord_am_ehir_dep_prem_percent'
     });

   var employeePremium = totalPremium * employeePercent;
     var dependentPremium = (to1talPremium - employeeOnlyPremium) * dependentPercent;
     var companyPremium = totalPremium - employeePremium - dependentPremium;

   //set field values
     currentRecord.setValue({
       fieldID: 'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_month_prem', employeePremium
     });
     currentRecord.setValue({
       fieldID: 'custrecord_am_ehir_dep_month_prem', dependentPremium
     });
     currentRecord.setValue({
       fieldID: 'custrecord_am_ehir_co_month_prem', companyPremium
     });
   }
2. It is **fieldId** and not **fieldID** or **fieldid**.

eg.

```
var totalPremium = currentRecord.getValue({
  fieldId: 'custrecord_am_ehir_total_month_prem'
});
```

3. To set a value using SS2.0 you need to pass object containing 2 properties **fieldId** and **value**.

So, to set a value you need to do the following.

```
currentRecord.setValue({
  fieldId:'custrecord_am_ehir_emp_month_prem', 
  value: employeePremium
});
```

For further readings, you can refer to [Record Module](https://system.na3.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4267255811.html) in NetSuite Help